# Kubernetes user authentication with certificate

Tags: kubernetes

I am playing around with Minikube and I created a test user with certificates (mueller). He has set the CN of his certificate to mueller and the O to development.

Here is my role:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
 namespace: development
 name: read-development-pods
rules:
 - apiGroups: [""]
   resources: ["pods"]
   verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

and my rolebinding:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
 name: read-development-pods-rb
 namespace: development
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: mueller
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: read-development-pods
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Also I got my certificates set to the kubeconfig. The rules work fine.

Now my question is, can I get rid of my rolebinding, because having a rolebinding for each user is not very comfortable and I think I read somewhere that Kubernetes is able to use the O-field of the users certificate to automatically bind to the roles that are written in that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you've successfully confirmed entity object within one of K8s Authentication [strategies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#authentication-strategies) in Kubernetes API, typical request may consists of some [attribute](http://ttps://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#review-your-request-attributes) properties which defines a way how the cluster visitor can be authorized through one of the specific [modules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#authorization-modules).

As per official Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#x509-client-certs):

> As of Kubernetes 1.4, client certificates can also indicate a user’s
>   group memberships using the certificate’s organization fields. To
>   include multiple group memberships for a user, include multiple
>   organization fields in the certificate.
>
> For example, using the openssl command line tool to generate a
>   certificate signing request:
>
> **openssl req -new -key jbeda.pem -out jbeda-csr.pem -subj
>   "/CN=jbeda/O=app1/O=app2"**

Comment: sure but can I get rid of the RoleBinding and let kubernetes use the O-field as groups and automatiaclly bind a user to this group?

Comment: You can use particular group to which user is assigned and declare this group in `RoleBinding` definition.